# ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'import matplotlib.pyplot as plt'

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import numpy as np
style.use('ggplot')

x,y = np.loadtxt(r'C:\Users\npatel\Documents\Coremotion Data\MotionData\data.txt',unpack = True, delimiter = '/s')
print(x)
print(y)
plt.show()
```

results in

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'import matplotlib.pyplot as plt'
```

I am trying to display accelerometer values from csv file but this error pops up.If anyone knows other method to display accelerometer values(x,y,z) against time in 2D in python, help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked your data yet?

Comment: Yes @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams My data is normal but i dont kow why the error is coming, my data is in csv format in excel.

Comment: @Cyzanfar yes i already did that

Comment: You opened up `data.txt` and looked at it?

Comment: how does the data look in the text file?

Comment: could not convert string to float: b'-0.002660268    0.011763552     0.005951784' now this error is coming @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: thanks @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams my data file was different

Comment: @Cyzanfar it is list of 3 values with space

Comment: @NehiPatel then that's your problem. It wont convert it to a floating number if the string has spaces

Comment: @Cyzanfar then i need to add coma in the list of 400 values ? That i would have to manually so is'nt there any option?

Comment: @Cyzanfar  i changed my file to csv that is in excel so i cant add comas there so why this error? could not convert string to float: b'time,x,y,z'

Comment: You would need to separate values by whitespace so you can grab each value

Comment: `'time,x,y,z' ` this is not a float or int value

Comment: @Cyzanfar my data already has space between it

Comment: Please don't substantively change your question after asking it. It makes all of the comments and answers appear non-sensical.

Comment: @Robᵩ sorry about that, i'll change it back but can u help me solve the error? its still coming :could not convert string to float:

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `'/s'` means what you think it means. Specifically, it doesn't mean "whitespace". Get rid of the `delimiter` keyword to `np.loadtxt()`, and accept the default value, which is to separate the fields by any white space.

```
np.loadtxt(r'data.txt',unpack=True)
```

At some point after asking your original question, you've changed your dataset to be comma-separated rather when whitespace-separated. For comma-separated values, you should specify `','` as the delimiter:

```
np.loadtxt(r'data.txt', delimiter=',', unpack=True)
```

Reference: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html

Comment: I removed the delimiter still this error is coming: could not convert string to float: b'13:34:36,-0.009894175,0.013596042,0.004239134'

Comment: In your original question, your data file does not have commas. But now your data file does have commas. Which is it?

Comment: my error is - could not convert string to float: b'-0.009894175,0.013596042,0.004239134' when i have a csv files with 3 columns of float values

Comment: If your data file has fields separated by comma, use `delimiter=','`. If your data file has fields separated by whitespace, don't use any `delimiter=`.

Comment: I removed the delimiter still i am having the error of could not convert string to float

Comment: my error remains the same after making changes you suggested  : could not convert string to float: b'-0.009894175,0.013596042,0.004239134'

Comment: Look at the error message. Notice how the floating-point values are delimited by commas. For this data set, use `delimiter=','`. Now look at the error message in your original question. Notice how **those** floating-point values are delimited by whitespace. For **that** data set, don't use any `delimiter=`.

Comment: Oh okay i got what you are saying and I made changes according to that but now the error says: could not convert string to float: